# Hibernate is mapping OffsetDateTime field with timezone based on System default

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am using PostgreSQL as the back end database and I have a table with a timestamptz column. Database server is set to use UTC as default (not related here though).

Then I have an entity class for this table and have this timestamptz column maps to `OffsetDateTime`, e.g.:

```
@Entity public class MyTable {
    ...
    private OffsetDateTime timestamptzCol;
    ...
}
```

Everything works except the object constructed by Hibernate is using System default timezone instead of following the exact value returned by PostgreSQL ("UTC" in this case). I traced it back to the Hibernate source code in `OffsetDateTimeJavaDescriptor.java` line 127

```
return OffsetDateTime.ofInstant( ts.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault() );
```

There `ts` is of type `java.sql.Timestamp`.

Surely I understand that `java.sql.Timestamp` is basically a `java.util.Date`, which is without timezone element. So my question is, how to instruct Hibernate to preserve the exact timestamptz value (with timezone) when mapping to `OffsetDateTime`?

Answer (score 1):

IMO, Hibernate's behaviour looks more natural rather than your desire, at least it is consistent with the output `OffsetDateTime.now()`.

However, in any case you need to write some code to support desired behaviour, for example:

```java
// OffsetDateTimeUTCJavaDescriptor.java

public class OffsetDateTimeUTCJavaDescriptor extends OffsetDateTimeJavaDescriptor {

    public static final OffsetDateTimeUTCJavaDescriptor INSTANCE = new OffsetDateTimeUTCJavaDescriptor();

    @Override
    public <X> OffsetDateTime wrap(X value, WrapperOptions options) {
        OffsetDateTime result = super.wrap(value, options);
        if (result == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return result.withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    }
    
}

// OffsetDateTimeUTCType.java

public class OffsetDateTimeUTCType extends OffsetDateTimeType {

    public OffsetDateTimeUTCType() {
        setJavaTypeDescriptor(OffsetDateTimeUTCJavaDescriptor.INSTANCE);
    }

    @Override
    public OffsetDateTime seed(SharedSessionContractImplementor session) {
        return super.seed(session).withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    }

    @Override
    public OffsetDateTime next(OffsetDateTime current, SharedSessionContractImplementor session) {
        return super.next(current, session).withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    }

}
```

Now, the problem is `Hibernate` (at least `v5`) does not provide any option to sync database metadata with JPA metadata, so you need to do that ~manually and actually two options exist:

I. completely override built-in definition of `OffsetDateTime` type, and use new convention everywhere:

```java
// package-info.java

@TypeDef(name = "OffsetDateTimeUTC", typeClass = OffsetDateTimeUTCType.class, defaultForType = OffsetDateTime.class)
package com.tld;

import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef;
import com.tld.OffsetDateTimeUTCType;

import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
```

II. just register new type definition without overriding defaults:

```java
// package-info.java

@TypeDef(name = "OffsetDateTimeUTC", typeClass = OffsetDateTimeUTCType.class)
package com.tld;

import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef;
import com.tld.OffsetDateTimeUTCType;

import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
```

and apply it to columns via:

```java
@Type(type = "OffsetDateTimeUTC")
```

Comment: Hummm, ok, its interesting to see your approach. But I am not after a hardcoded solution (sorry if I wasn't clear). Only because the db was set to use UTC, it doesn't mean it has to be UTC (it can be any server timezone). So the answer I am after is for Hibernate to map the EXACT timestamptz value (as you can see from pgAdmin) to OffsetDateTime (with the same timezone).

Comment: PostgreSQL does store UTC time in `timestamptz`. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/datatype-datetime.html: For timestamp with time zone, the internally stored value is always in UTC (Universal Coordinated Time, traditionally known as Greenwich Mean Time, GMT). An input value that has an explicit time zone specified is converted to UTC using the appropriate offset for that time zone.

Comment: Yeah, totally agree with the "stored" value being in UTC. However, the SELECT value is always converted based on the server time zone config (the very same page you linked above "When a timestamp with time zone value is output, it is always converted from UTC to the current timezone zone, and displayed as local time in that zone") and is returned back to Hibernate.

Comment: even if you were able to call rs.getObject(int,OffsetDateTime.class) you would get UTC offset, because JDBC driver [enforces UTC offset](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/5709a20fbef453749d2394e11502527e4a3ab5bb/pgjdbc/src/main/java/org/postgresql/jdbc/PgResultSet.java#L670). So, would you mind clarifying what offset you are interested in? UTC? Java? DB?

Comment: If you call `getString()` in the JDBC driver, you get the converted datetime+offset string, which is the same as you do SELECT in pgAdmin (i.e. converted to the db server time zone setting). This is the expected value I am after.

Comment: I'm afraid the result of `#getString` depends on client timezone (ZoneId.systemDefault(), -Duser.timezone=, etc)

Comment: Thats surely is not what I observed. It has nothing to do with local system timezone setting. It reads the raw bytes from Postgres, which is the converted value from UTC using the server time zone config.

Answer (score 0):

### Avoid legacy classes

- Do not use `java.sql.Timestamp`.
- Do not use `java.util.Date`.

These terribly flawed classes were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310 in Java 8+. Sun, Oracle, and the JCP community all gave up on those legacy classes; so should you.

JDBC 4.2+ requires all drivers to support for *java.time*. Jakarta Persistence and Hibernate have been updated to support *java.time*.

So just use *java.time*. There is no point in studying the bizarre design and behavior of those legacy classes.

### `OffsetDateTime`

For a Postgres column of type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, use Java class `OffsetDateTime`. You will always get back a date-time value with an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from UTC.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
myResultSet.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

And retrieval.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myPreparedStatement.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the background information, they should be helpful for others. However, none of those addressed my question, so may be you can try adding relevant information?